# Why do I need to use pecl to install PDO and ibm_db2

Tags: php, db2, pecl

I built 64bit versions of php-7.0.10 and php-5.6.25 with many options including:

```
--with-pdo-odbc=ibm-db2,$IBM_DB2
--with-pdo-oci=instantclient,$ORACLE_VERSION,12.1
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
--with-pdo-dblib=$LIBS_PREFIX
--with-ibm-db2=$IBM_DB2
```

everything looked fine with "php -i | egrep -i 'db2|pdo'" reporting:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown on line 0
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-dba=shared' '--enable-exif' '--enable-fpm' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--enable-intl' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-opcache' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' '--with-bz2=/versions64/local' '--with-curl=/versions64/local' '--with-freetype-dir=/versions64/local' '--with-gd=/versions64/local' '--with-gdbm=/opt/dweb/chroot-staging/usr/lib64' '--with-gettext=/opt/dweb/chroot-staging/usr/lib64' '--with-icu-dir=/versions64/local' '--with-iodbc=/versions64/local' '--with-jpeg-dir=/versions64/local' '--with-kerberos=/versions64/local' '--with-ldap=/versions64/local' '--with-libxml-dir=/versions64/local' '--with-mcrypt=/versions64/local' '--with-ibm-db2=/opt/IBM/db2/V10.5' '--with-pdo-odbc=ibm-db2,/opt/IBM/db2/V10.5' '--with-mysql=/versions64/mariadb-5.5.50' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-msqls=/versions64/local' '--with-mssql=/versions64/local' '--with-oci8=instantclient,/versions64/oracle_instantclient/instantclient_12_1' '--with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/versions64/oracle_instantclient/instantclient_12_1,12.1' '--with-openssl=/versions64/local' '--with-pcre-regex=/versions64/local' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-dblib=/versions64/local' '--with-png-dir=/versions64/local' '--with-sybase-ct=/versions64/local' '--with-tidy=/versions64/local' '--with-xsl=/versions64/local' '--with-zlib-dir=/versions64/local' '--with-imap=../../imap-uw-c-client/imap-2007f' '--with-imap-ssl=/versions64/local' '--prefix=/versions64/php-5.6.25' '--with-config-file-path=/versions64/php-5.6.25' 'CC=gcc'
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql
ODBC library => ibm-db2
ODBC_INCLUDE => -I/opt/IBM/db2/V10.5/include
ODBC_LFLAGS => -L/opt/IBM/db2/V10.5/lib
ODBC_LIBS => -ldb2
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => dblib, mysql, oci, odbc, sqlite
pdo_dblib
PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib => enabled
pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /tmp/mysql.sock => /tmp/mysql.sock
PDO_OCI
PDO Driver for OCI 8 and later => enabled
PDO_ODBC
PDO Driver for ODBC (ibm-db2) => enabled
pdo_odbc.db2_instance_name => no value => no value
pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

However attempts to use "db2_connect" failed with "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function db2_connect()""

Looking around the web there are umpteen articles explaining I need to use PECL to install db2 support. Why? What has the above done?

Then when I try 'pdo install ibm_db2' I get an message saying I need to install pdo first! Was it not installed as part of the original build?

Please explain what pecl is doing that ./configure + make install does not.

Comment: PDO has its own drivers. PDO itself does not provide the generic `nameofdb_*()` function sets. Just because PDO has db2 support enabled doesn't mean the "generic" functions are available too.

Comment: I was intending to allow users to choose between PDO and the db2_xxxx methods. Still I think this is a slight distraction. I would still like to understand, for this case, what PDO is doing that initial build with latest versions is not.